# Printing in specific coordinates of a document

Tags: printing, forms

I have a document which contains certain fields that need to be completed by hand.  I am trying to eliminate this task.

What I would like to do is:

- Scan the document and measure the dimensions.
- Find where the fields are located in the document.
- Create a new, empty document with the same dimensions as the original and type all the necessary details inside at locations matching the input fields.
- Print this "input" file, but in the printer I will have inserted a hard copy of the original, unfilled document.

Unfortunately the original empty document must be used at all times since I get it from my office.  Otherwise, I would scan the file and add the values I need with some photo editing software.

Is there any way to do what I've described?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. The important parts of questions asked here are the details of what research and efforts have already been made. This will eliminate duplication of efforts and also shows us you have attempted to resolve it yourself, not just expect us to do it. Please [edit] your question to include those details and we will try to help you from there.

Comment: What you describe is commonly done.  It isn't clear what the impediment is.  When you say the original document must be used at all times, do you mean that it's an electronic form and company policy dictates that it must be used in that manner, or that the file is always "open" (and "locked"?), and you have a problem saving it or printing it in order to accomplish this?  Can you clarify what you've tried to do and what happens when you do it?

Comment: The original document is provided from the local post office.It's a document with specific dimensions and certain paper thickness and quality,thus i can't reproduce the material it has to be printed on that.I have already scanned the file and i have been trying to find software for the past 2 hours that will allow me to pinpoint where in the scanned file the empty fields are located but with no luck.

Comment: You can use word with appropriately positioned [text boxes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-delete-a-text-box-6cbd2c67-2c40-4096-9dcb-9ad6ddbb2b25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to do this myself, I would use Desktop Publishing software (inDesign,Scribus), but this can also be done in Word using Text Boxes.

In either case, simply place the scan of the form as 100% size so that it fills the page. Ensure you have the scan cropped and placed properly by printing it, placing that document on top of the original form and holding it up to a light source.

You can either place the scanned image as a **watermark** or as an image set to "behind text".

Then you can easily place the text fields so that they are in the appropriate places. Once this is done, you can either remove the image or leave it and print on plain paper (if regulations allow).

I have done this many times when doing e.g. placeholders, personalized tickets etc.

---

You can go further by making a VBA macro and Form that collects the data you want and then auto-fills the text boxes.